# When are static arrays allocated and when are they deallocated?

Tags: arrays, fortran

To be clear, let us define static arrays as arrays whose shape and bounds are known at compile time, and define automatic arrays as arrays whose shape and bounds are not known at compile time but are not `allocatable` arrays of Fortran. In Fortran, automatic arrays can appear only in `subroutine/function`. And `save` is not allowed for automatic arrays.

In `subroutine/function` a static array's values can be retained between invocations by specifying `save`. Consider the case of not specifying `save` for a static array in a `subroutine`. Then, will the static array be automatically deallocated each time when the subroutine returns? If this is the case, then static arrays behave in the same way as automatic arrays, meaning no performance advantage over automatic arrays. Is it possible that all static arrays are allocated at the beginning of a run and are never deallocated until the program ends?

Comment: The standard does not say. Both behaviours you describe are possible and standard conforming, and both have been implemented in compilers historically. Somebody more knowledgeable of the Standard document can quote the appropriate chapter and verse.

Comment: In Fortran automatic arrays can exist outside a function and subroutine.

Comment: @francescalus  could you give an example? At least, `gfortran` would raise: `Error: The module or main program array 'a' at (1) must have constant shape`

Comment: `integer :: n=1; block; real x(n); end block; end`

Comment: @francescalus  I did not realize automatic array can be defined in a `block` since I seldom use `block` (only use it when adding temporary diagnostic codes in an existing code). Thanks for the information.